# Query circular attribute in graphql

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I have the following scheme

```
type Product {
   code: ID!
   services: [ServiceGroup]
}

type ServiceGroup {
   code: String!
   options: [ServiceItem]
}

type ServiceItem {
   itemName: String!
   groups: [ServiceGroup]
}
```

Now in the client, how can I query a product and its services considering that `groups` is nested with more groups.

```
gql`
 query getProduct($code: ID!) { 
     product(code: $code) {
        code
        services {
           code
           options {
               itemName
               groups {
                  code
                  options {
                    ....
                  }
                }
            }
        }
     }
  }
`
```

Comment: What is the problem that nesting is causing?

Comment: The problem is how can I query that infinitely nested groups attribute?

Comment: GraphQL trivially supports "circular" nested parent-child queries to arbitrary depth.  This is generally considered a feature, not a bug.  Is your question how to write a query that "stops" at the desired depth?

Comment: yes, basically how can I write a query that will continue querying until there is no more data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphQL trivially supports "circular" nested parent-child queries to arbitrary depth. GraphQL resolves fields recursively, [stopping when all field values resolve to scalars](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Executing-Fields).

In your example, the query would terminate if you removed `options {....}`, because `code` is a scalar.  The right place to stop depends on your use case.

Here's a [runnable example](https://graphql.org/swapi-graphql/?query=query%20AllFilms(%24f%3AInt)%20%7B%0A%20%20allFilms(first%3A%24f)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20films%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20characterConnection(first%3A%20%24f)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20characters%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20filmConnection%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20films%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20characterConnection%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20characters%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20filmConnection%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20films%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&operationName=AllFilms&variables=%7B%0A%20%20%22f%22%3A%202%0A%7D) using the "circular" character-film relation in the Star Wars API.  The query terminates when there are no more [Object Type](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#object-types-and-fields) fields to resolve.  This silly example is overly nested: the results quickly become repetitive. Repetitive nesting has its uses, though.  It can reshape the result set, for instance inverting a `parents > children` structure  to `children > parents`.

```
query AllFilms($f:Int) {
  allFilms(first:$f) {
    films {
      title
      characterConnection(first: $f) {
        characters {
          name
          filmConnection {
            films {
              title
              characterConnection {
                characters {
                  name
                  filmConnection {
                    films {
                      title
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that gql does not allow the [nesting of recursive fragments](https://hashinteractive.com/blog/graphql-recursive-query-with-fragments/). In the provided example you have a circular dependency which gql cannot handle.
The article provided shows an approach with a finite recursive depth.

- Workarounds would be to fetch only identifies such as `code` or `itemName` and refetching those objects when needed.
- If the entire structure is needed as one object you might consider to fetch the structure as a JSON object (encoded as `String`) and parsing it locally. **Using this method is not type safe!**

Answer (score 0):

The query would have to be dynamically written in the client based on what the depth is. You could have another query field that returns this.